# How do I change the height of picker input in from shinywidget?

Tags: r, shiny, shinywidgets

I use pickerInput from shinyWidget

```
div(class = "choosechannel",
pickerInput(inputId = "choosechannel", label = "business channel", width = "150px",
choices = c("In-Branch", "Agency", "Affinity", "Corporate", "Credit Life"),
multiple = TRUE, selected = c("In-Branch", "Agency", "Affinity", "Corporate", "Credit Life"),
options = list(height = 10)))
```

I want to change the height of pickerInput 
Here are the codes that I have tried to use:

```
tags$style(".choosechannel-button {height: 26.5px; min-height: 26.5px; padding: 0px;}")

tags$head( tags$style( HTML("#choosechannel-button {font-size: 13px; height: 26.5px; min-height: 26.5px;}")))

tags$style(".choosechannel-container {height: 26.5px; min-height: 26.5px; padding: 0px;}")

tags$head( tags$style( HTML("#choosechannel-container {font-size: 13px; height: 26.5px; min-height: 26.5px;}")))
```

None of them works. Does anyone know how to do it?

edit :
I've tried `.choosechannel .btn {height: 26.5px; font-size: 13px;}` within tags$style, as suggested by Wilmar van Ommeren in his answer. It almost work. It still has white space underneath it.

It looks like this:

[image: Here]

Answer (score 3):

You are almost there. What you want is to change the `.btn` class in your `.choosechannel` class. You can point to a class inherited by another class by using a dot (`.choosechannel .btn {...}`).

### Working example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style(".choosechannel .btn {height: 26.5px; min-height: 26.5px; padding: 0px;}"),
  div(class = "choosechannel",
      pickerInput(inputId = "choosechannel", label = "business channel", width = "150px",
                  choices = c("In-Branch", "Agency", "Affinity", "Corporate", "Credit Life"),
                  multiple = TRUE, selected = c("In-Branch", "Agency", "Affinity", "Corporate", "Credit Life"),
                  options = list(height = 10))) 
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I've tried your code and it almost work. There's still white space underneath the button. I've provided the picture in my edited question. Please review. Thank you.

Comment: That's not the case on my pc. Does this occur if you copy and run my exact piece of code? If not you should post a minimal reproducible example, so I can help you further.

Comment: Yes, I tried your exact whole code on a new empty shiny web app. I added "body{background-color: #00008B}" in tags$style to add background and it gives me the same result as the problem I wrote above; that there's white space underneath the button.